# 2023 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

### The 2023 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase [Complete]
2. Primary phase [Skipped]
3. Election phase [Complete]

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the **[official election page](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/election)** for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta − just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).